# Dynamic HTML table with Javascript checkboxes puzzle - how to access checkbox.checked from outside of the function?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, dynamic, html-table

Before I begin, I should mention I am using Javascript but I'm not using JQuery.

I have a function which obtains data from a site and displays it in an HTML table.

I would like to add a checkbox to each row, and find if each one has been checked or not later (i.e. when a button is clicked), outside of the function that creates the table.

The reason for this is that the function that makes the table only runs once and can't check if the box is checked or not (the user hasn't had a chance to check any yet!).

Each checkbox relates to other data displayed on the same row, which I can access outside of `_cb_findItemsAdvanced(root)` by declaring the 'items' variable before the function begins. However, I can't seem to do this for checkboxes.

I can add normal checkboxes to the table with:

```
"<input type=checkbox...".
```

However, I can't seem to access them from outside of the function that makes the table (and calls for the data). I've tried:

document.form1.sharedCheckboxName

It didn't seem to work.

I have tried everything, from creating a global checkbox array and trying to specify

```
" + checkbox[i] + "
```

instead of

```
"<input type=checkbox...",
```

but it didn't work. I know my current code has just specified a variable of type checkbox, rather than what I want which is to populate the table with my existing, global, array of checkboxes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am lost! I hope you're not, after reading that! :-)

Here is my code:

```
var items;
var checkbox = [];
function _cb_findItemsAdvanced(root)
{
    items = root.findItemsAdvancedResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];

    var html = [];
    html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><form name="form1"><tbody>');


for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)  
{
    var item     = items[i];
    var title    = item.title;
    var pic      = item.galleryURL;
    var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
    checkbox[i] = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox[i].type = "checkbox";
    checkbox[i].name = "name";
    checkbox[i].value = "value";
    checkbox[i].id = "id" + i;
    if (null != title && null != viewitem)
    {
      html.push('<tr><td>' + '<img src="' + pic + '" border="0">' + '</td>' +
        '<td><a href="' + viewitem + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></td>' + '<td> <input type = "' + checkbox[i].type + '" + </t></tr>');
    }

}   



html.push('</tbody></table>');
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");

}

if (checkbox[0].checked)
{
     alert("HI"); //but nothing happens
}
```

Comment: you can't mix html strings with DOM element objects.
you have created a checkbox array. in each iteration you create a checkbox element (document.createElement()) but then you never use it. what you did is just creating a different checkbox in each row using html string

Comment: "I know my current code has just specified a variable of type checkbox" (and then used this variable to specify a type in the HTML string). I just left it in to try and show what I am trying to do - use the created checkbox elements in my table. Are you saying this is not possible? :-)

Comment: what you want to achieve is possible in more than one way.
but it will be easier if you can tell where is the button that should check if the checkboxes are checked or not, is it a single button or a button on every row?

Comment: My button is at the bottom of the page - I intend for the user to look through the displayed data, check the box beside any results of interest, and press the button to indicate that they are finished checking boxes. I plan then to use a for loop to find which information is of interest by which box had been ticked (eg     for (var x = 0; var < items.length; ++x)
    {
if (checkboxarray[x].checked)
{
mystring += items[x].sellerInfo.sellerName + ", ";
}
}

Comment: I know you're not using jQuery, but this would be pretty trivial using jQuery. It might be time to see if it is appropriate to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using html string forget about the checkboxes array.

your form should wrap the table not the other way around.
give your form an id

```
<form id="form1">
```

get the form and find all checkboxes

```
function findCheckedItems() {

var checkedItems = [];
var form = getElementById('form1');
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
var checkboxIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
     if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox') {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
               var data = item[checkboxIndex];
               checkedItems.push(data);
               // do whatever you like with the data
          }
          checkboxIndex++;
      }
}

return checkedItems;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :-) I finally managed to get it working. I didn't use your exact method as I couldn't get it working (I had already tried giving the form an id but it didn't seem to work). This is probably my fault, due to bad html code or something. But you inspired me to try again using 'getElementsById'. I got it to work by using '<input type = "checkbox" id="1' + i + '">' to id checkboxes. I then used a for loop for the rest - (document.getElementById("1"+pp).checked){myString += items[pp].sellerInfo[0].sellerUserName + ", ";} Thank you again, very much appreciated :-)

Comment: Happy to help.

even in this portion of your html code you have plenty of errors.
If you really care about the quality of your code I advise you to validate it against HTML validator service. better yet, use some kind of editor that marks this errors when you code it, (WebStorm is great IMO).
Passing validation will be tough at first but it will make your code error free and also teach you how to correctly structure your html.